# Removable media holding D drive letter

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have on my system some SD card or removable media drive which by default takes the D drive letter.

I have this:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> get-volume | where DriveType -Match "Removable"

DriveLetter FileSystemLabel FileSystem DriveType HealthStatus SizeRemaining Size
----------- --------------- ---------- --------- ------------ ------------- ----
E                                      Removable Healthy                0 B  0 B
```

And I want to change it to G like this:

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> get-volume | where DriveType -Match "Removable" |Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter G
```

But I get:

> Set-Partition : One or more parameter values passed to the method were invalid.
>       At line:1 char:50
>       + ... | where DriveType -Match "Removable" |Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter G
>       +                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (PS_StorageCmdlets:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-Partition],
>          CimException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 4,Set-Partition

How can I change this? Or what is the issue? I tried with the get-disk to pass but doesn't work either.
I can change in the computer management gui but I need commandline.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with something like this.

```
$DriveLetter = (Get-Volume | Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq "Removable"}).DriveLetter
Get-Partition -DriveLetter $DriveLetter | Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter G
```

Comment: Not working for me on a memory reader, this is a device, but no partition `No MSFT_Partition objects found with property 'DriveLetter' equal to 'H'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.`

Answer (score 0):

Removable drives (at least without media) does not work with `Set-Partition`

Worked around this by scripting `diskpart`

```
"SELECT VOLUME D`nREMOVE LETTER=D`nASSIGN LETTER=G NOERR" | diskpart
```

This selects volume d, removes given letter and assigns new letter (ignoring error)